# How to render html iFrame from Drupal paragraph using plain text field

Tags: drupal, twig, paragraph

I have a site where I am trying to allow the site owners to enter an iframe embed code (using the paragraphs module) on a page and then will render this out adding a container to make it always responsive.

I am running into an issue with twig always outputting as text however. It works perfectly if I use a formatted text field and then click "source" and paste the code in from the dashboard, but obviously that is super clunky for the site admin and very prone to errors. I'd like to just have a plain text field instead. Trouble is even when I use `{{ content.field_embed[0].value | raw }}` it comes out as text. is there anyway around this that I am missing? Would like to not resort to having the user work with the CK editor just for a simple embed

Comment: Make sure you are saving the input as `html` and not as `entities` in the database

Comment: Thanks, this does sound like it could be the issue, do you know how would I go about changing this behavior in drupal 8 though, did some searches, but not seeing anything about it in documentation?

Comment: I'd start with verifying the content in your database first to be sure this is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mhfleming, I was having the exact same issue as you. Using the filter `raw` was still giving me the escaped iframe, like in `&lt;iframe ...`. I even thought the issue could be related to one of the contrib modules `Twig Tweak` and `Twig Field Value`, which the site I'm working on uses, but those were not the culprits.

I was able to get my code working with the following Twig snippet:

```
{% set embed_code = {
  '#type': 'processed_text',
  '#text': content.field_embed_code[0]['#context']['value'],
  '#format': 'full_html',
} %}
<div class="responsive-embed">
  {{ embed_code }}
</div>
```

Your code looks very similar. Try replacing the field name with `field_embed` and give this snippet a try.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and came to thread and found Bruno's answer which gave me an idea that worked for me for a **plain text** field.

Override the `field--name.html.twig` that has the iframe code in it. Then print the field using this structure (kint is your friend here) `{{ item.content['#context']['value']|raw }}`

This worked for me and rendered the iframe just fine. Hope it helps someone else.